# Three Coupled PDE. Is my approach in the right way?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, elliptic-equations, linear-pde

I have the following three PDEs

\begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{\partial \theta_h}{\partial x} + \beta_h (\theta_h - \theta_w) &=& 0,\\
  \frac{\partial \theta_c}{\partial y} + \beta_c (\theta_c - \theta_w) &=& 0,\\
  \lambda_h \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial x^2} + \lambda_c V \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial y^2} - \frac{\partial \theta_h}{\partial x} - V\frac{\partial \theta_c}{\partial y} &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}

From the first and second equation i expressed $\frac{\partial \theta_h}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \theta_c}{\partial y}$ in terms of $\theta_w$. Then i substituted these in the third equation to yield

$$\lambda_h \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial x^2} + \lambda_c V \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial y^2} - (\beta_h+V\beta_c)\theta_w+(\beta_h\theta_h+V\beta_c\theta_c) = 0$$

The third PDE turns out to be a second order linear Elliptic PDE as $\lambda_h$,$\lambda_c$ and $V$ are all positive constants. I have reached a canonical form for this second order PDE. This PDE is defined on a rectangle with Neumann conditions. I plan to do the following next;

1. Calculate $\theta_w(x,y)$ from the second order PDE.
2. Plug them in
   the first two to obtain $\theta_h$ and $\theta_c$

Am i following a correct approach or is there any subtlety i am over-looking ?

***Attempt***

The boundary conditions for the problem are as follows:

The PDE needs to be solved on a rectangular region where $x$ varies between $0$ to $1$ and $y$ varies between $0$ to $1$.

$$\frac{\partial \theta_w(0,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \theta_w(1,y)}{\partial x}=0 $$

$$\frac{\partial \theta_w(x,0)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \theta_w(x,1)}{\partial y}=0 $$

$$\theta_h(0,y)=1 $$$$\theta_c(x,0)=0$$

After the suggestions from @Christoph here i have the following two linear third order differential equations:

\begin{eqnarray}
 \lambda_h F''' - 2 \lambda_h \beta_h F'' + \left( (\lambda_h \beta_h - 1) \beta_h - \mu \right) F' + \beta_h^2 F &=& 0,\\
 V \lambda_c G''' - 2 V \lambda_c \beta_c G'' + \left( (\lambda_c \beta_c - 1) V \beta_c + \mu \right) G' + V \beta_c^2 G &=& 0,
\end{eqnarray}

Both these ODEs now need to be converted to individual Boundary value problems using the BC(s). On substituting

$$\theta_w(x,y) = e^{-\beta_h x} F(x) e^{-\beta_c y} G(y)$$ into the give BC(s), i arrive at the following

$$e^{-\beta_cy}F(0)G(y)=1$$
$$e^{-\beta_hx}F(x)G(0)=0$$
$$e^{-\beta_cy}G(y)[F'(0)-\beta_hF(0)]=0$$
$$e^{-\beta_cy}e^{-\beta_h}G(y)[F'(1)-\beta_hF(1)]=0$$
$$e^{-\beta_hx}F(x)[G'(0)-\beta_cG(0)]=0$$
$$e^{-\beta_hx}e^{-\beta_c}F(x)[G'(1)-\beta_cG(1)]=0$$

Following this (keeping in mind that exponential cannot attain a 0 value), i arrive at the following simplifications:

$$G(0)=0$$
$$G'(0)=0$$
$$\frac{G'(1)}{G(1)}=\beta_c$$
$$\frac{F'(0)}{F(0)}=\beta_h$$
$$\frac{F'(1)}{F(1)}=\beta_h$$

The ODEs are of third order and although i have six BC(s), on decoupling the BC(s) i get just 5. Am i misunderstanding something or is there some other way ?

***Attempt 2***

As @Christoph advised I made the following changes:
$$\bar{{\theta_h}}(x,y):=\theta_h(x,y)-1$$
and the ansatz
$$\theta_w(x,y)=e^{-\beta_hx}f(x)e^{-\beta_cy}g(y)$$ such that  $F(x) := \int f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ and $G(y) := \int g(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$

The third order linear DEs we arrive at still remain the same.
For figuring out the b.c.(s), the ansatz became:
$$\theta_w(x,y)=e^{-\beta_hx}F'(x)e^{-\beta_cy}G'(y)$$

But the boundary conditions now take the following form

For $F$:
$$F(0)=0$$
$$\frac{F''(0)}{F'(0)}=\beta_h$$
$$\frac{F''(1)}{F'(1)}=\beta_h$$

For $G$:
$$G(0)=0$$
$$\frac{G''(0)}{G'(0)}=\beta_c$$
$$\frac{G''(1)}{G'(1)}=\beta_c$$

Now i have three b.c. (s) for each boundary value problem viz. $F$ and $G$.
Each BVP (one each of $F$ and $G$) now involve one *Dirichlet* and two *Robin* type b.c.

Comment: But you still have the unknown functions $\theta_h$ and $\theta_c$ in your PDE after this substitution?!

Comment: Also, there should be a factor $V$ in front of $\frac{\partial \theta_c}{\partial y}$.

Comment: @Christoph Made the edit, you were right about the $V$. Can't $(\beta_h\theta_h+V\beta_c\theta_c)$ be together considered a variable say $k$ which would be a function of $x$ and $y$ . And a second order linear PDE requires the coefficients to be the functions of the independent variables $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Christoph. Any suggestion on how tot tackle the problem if what i was thinking is wrong

Comment: It is correct to have 5 boundary conditions. As the scale of $F$ and $G$ is free for a homogeneous equation, fixing the scales adds two additional equations, making 7 conditions for a state of 6 function values and derivatives plus one parameter $\mu$. // In the  second approach either one of the cited BC is redundant or there is some other error, as 8 equations for 7 variables is usually not solvable.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for this guidance. I will go through my notes once again. In that case i will have a well defined Eigenvalue problem for only $G$  which needs to be solved for eigs and then used in the $F$ equation.

Comment: The problem is that with this approach it can very easily happen that the only solution for $F$ is the zero solution, that the solution space is zero-dimensional instead of positive dimensional.

Comment: @LutzL Can you suggest an alternative or some other approach through which thiese EBVPs can be tackled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few hints:

1. Solve the two first-order PDEs for $\theta_h, \theta_c$ as functions of $\theta_w$:
   \begin{eqnarray}
    \theta_h(x,y) &=& \beta_h e^{-\beta_h x} \int e^{\beta_h x} \theta_w(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x,\\
    \theta_c(x,y) &=& \beta_c e^{-\beta_c y} \int e^{\beta_c y} \theta_w(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}y.
   \end{eqnarray}
2. Eliminate $\theta_h, \theta_c$ in the second-order PDE to obtain the following equation for $\theta_w$:
   \begin{eqnarray}
      0 &=& e^{-\beta_h x} \left( \lambda_h e^{\beta_h x} \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial x^2} - \beta_h e^{\beta_h x} \theta_w + \beta_h^2 \int e^{\beta_h x} \theta_w \, \mathrm{d}x \right) +\\
      && + V e^{-\beta_c y} \left( \lambda_c e^{\beta_c y} \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial y^2} - \beta_c e^{\beta_c y} \theta_w + \beta_c^2 \int e^{\beta_c y} \theta_w \, \mathrm{d}y \right).
     \end{eqnarray}
3. Use separation of variables with the ansatz $\theta_w(x,y) = e^{-\beta_h x} f(x) e^{-\beta_c y} g(y)$. You should obtain two *linear third-order ODEs with constant coefficients* for $F(x) := \int f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ and $G(y) := \int g(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$:
   \begin{eqnarray}
    \lambda_h F''' - 2 \lambda_h \beta_h F'' + \left( (\lambda_h \beta_h - 1) \beta_h - \mu \right) F' + \beta_h^2 F &=& 0,\\
    V \lambda_c G''' - 2 V \lambda_c \beta_c G'' + \left( (\lambda_c \beta_c - 1) V \beta_c + \mu \right) G' + V \beta_c^2 G &=& 0,
   \end{eqnarray}
   with some separation constant $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$.
4. From the boundary conditions on $\theta_h, \theta_c, \theta_w$ you should obtain conditions on $F$, $G$. Once the BVPs with the third-order ODEs are solved, compute $f \equiv F'$, $g \equiv G'$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this guidance. I am trying to reproduce your steps. While substituting the ansatz for $\theta_w$ in the PDE of the 2nd step i am encountering a term $\int F(x) \mathrm{d}x$. Is this term responsible for producing the third order $F^{'''}$ term ? Is it some obvious thing i am missing ?

Comment: To rephrase my concern, Since $F$ is a guessed function how are we supposed to write $\int F(x) \mathrm{d}x$ ?

Comment: Yes, the last two equations in my answer were obtained by taking one more derivative in order to remove the antiderivatives of $F$ and $G$. Therefore, the third derivatives appear.

Comment: This was really helpful. So now the two linear third order ODEs must be solved separately to get $F$ and $G$ which will give a complete $\theta_w$. And then $\theta_h$ and $\theta_c$ could be determined from their individual relations. My only point of doubt is now the separation variable $\mu$. Will that come out from the boundary conditions on the two ODEs?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. From the boundary conditions on $\theta_h, \theta_c, \theta_w$ on the four faces of the rectangular domain you should obtain  boundary conditions for $F$ and $G$. The boundary-value problems (BVPs) for $F$ and $G$ should have solutions only for a discrete set of values $\mu_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For each of these values you might find solutions $F_n(x)$ and $G_n(y)$ of the BVPs, which you can finally add up to obtain a series representation $\theta_w(x,y) = \sum_n c_n e^{-\beta_h x} F_n(x) e^{-\beta_c y} G_n(y)$, with some coefficients $c_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I tried the steps suggested by you. While using the actual BC(s) provided, i wanted to develop two independent BVPs for each $F$ and $G$. When executing this step i reached 5 BCs. Since, the ODEs are third order linear, i need 3 BCs for each of them. I have edited the original question to show my attempt. Is there something i am missing ?

Comment: The problem comes from the non-homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions for $\theta_h$. You'll have to define a new function $\tilde{\theta}_h(x,y) := \theta_h(x,y) - 1$, for example, which satisfies $\tilde{\theta}_h(0,y) = 0$ (homogeneous Dirichlet b. c.). Then rewrite the PDE system for $(\tilde{\theta}_h,\theta_c,\theta_w)$ and proceed as before.
And I assume the homogeneous Neumann b. c. are all for $\theta_w$?

Comment: You are right . My bad. The homogeneous Neumann conditions are for $\theta_w$. Thanks for the help again. So you mean to say, i define this new variable and rewrite the PDE system again using this new variable. Following this, i follow the whole procedure  of eliminating the new $\theta_h$ and $\theta_c$ from the wall equation ultimately reaching a new variable seperated form. Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. There will be almost no change actually, since the addition of a constant 1 does not change the derivatives. I think there is also a small issue with my point 3. I'll edit it.

Comment: So the changes you made to point 3 do not change the third order ODEs obtained after variable seperation ? Asking because i retraced your steps with the previously suggested ansatz and reached them.

Comment: Yes, I think the third-order ODEs stay the same. The slight difference is that the derivatives $f \equiv F'$ and $g \equiv G'$ should appear in $\theta_w$ finally.

Comment: You were right.The substitution did not change the linear ODEs. (Also i had to not take derivatives to remove the integral )The introduction of $\bar\theta_h$ made all the b.c.(s) homogeneous and gives 3 b.c. for each third order boundary value problem. I edited the main question to add this new attempt. So,when i calculate $F$ and $G$, i should then take their derivatives to get $f$ , $g$ w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ respectively to arrive at $\theta_w$ ? Also, the b.c.(s) i am arriving at especially the third involving the fraction, are they usual?Thanks again for the precise instructions.

Comment: I believe that there is still some mistake, because in my opinion you should obtain conditions for $F(0)$ and $G(0)$ from the boundary conditions on $\theta_h, \theta_c$ (note that they involve integrals of $\theta_w$). $F''(1) = \beta_h F'(1)$ is a kind of Robin boundary condition. And yes, you need to take the derivatives of $F, G$ in the end to obtain $f, g$.

Comment: You were right again. I was using the $\frac{\partial\theta_h}{\partial x}$ expressions instead of the integral expression. I now have b.c. in terms of $F(0)$ and $G(0)$ but the other two b.c. in both cases now turn out to be Robin type. I have edited the _Attempt 2_ to reflect these changes. Do these b.c seem suitable ?

Comment: Also,  $\bar\theta_h(x,y)$ is the new function introduced to obtain a Dirichlet type b.c. So when i finally obtain $\bar\theta_h(x,y)$ i need to add $1$ to it to get the actual $\theta_h(x,y)$ **or** the solution from the new function viz.  is sufficient as it already incorporates this data ?

Comment: Yes, the b. c. are correct now I think. Once you get $\theta_w = e^{-\beta_h x} f(x) e^{-\beta_c y} g(y)$ you compute $\tilde{\theta}_h = e^{-\beta_h x} F(x) e^{-\beta_c y} g(y)$, which satisfies $\tilde{\theta}_h(0,y) = 0$. Therefore, you need to add $1$ to obtain $\theta_h$.

Comment: Perhaps we should not let the discussion get too long in the comments. Maybe it's best if you start a new question with your ODEs.

Comment: I do agree. This has already gotten too long. Your timely help made me understand a lot of key points and workarounds. Further, this probably would be very useful to others. I will make another question as i work on the ODEs.

Comment: I created a new question [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069768/eigen-values-of-a-third-order-linear-homogenous-ode]